# PHPMySQL: How to determine if value already exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameterized-query

I have a form button that I need to do two different things, based on user input and whether that input already exists in my database. If the input DOES NOT exist, then the button will create a new record. If it DOES exist, then the existing record will be updated.

Here's my PDO query as it stands now:

```
/* First, we need to discover whether the Proposal No. entered already exists in the
database. If it doesn't, then a new record will be created. If                                                                            
it does, then an existing record will be updated. */
$pNoExists = $con->prepare("SELECT ProposalNo FROM ptfp1"); 
$pNoExists->execute();
$row = $pNoExists->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I run $row = $pNoExists->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); through a while loop, all of the values for the field are present. Now I just need some guidance on how to use that in my button setup. This is what I want to do:

```
if($_POST['ButtonPush'] && input doesn't exist) {
  Create new record;
}
else {
  Update existing record;
}
```

Simple, right? But it's eluding me.

Comment: Having a WHERE clause in your SQL statement might help, rather than fetching every single proposal and then looping in PHP: let the database do what it's designed to do well

Comment: you can use `$count = mysqli_num_rows($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProposalNo = '$value'");` If `$count` is greater than 1, update existing.

Comment: Why don't you just use `INSERT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to do it in one step?

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have, I would do:

```
if($_POST['ButtonPush'] && array_search($all_values, $input_value)) {
    Create new
}
else {
    Update
}
```

However, like the comment above, you may want to simply add a where clause to your "SELECT" statement so you are not grabbing the entire database table contents every time. And, one could even convert the SELECT in to a SELECT COUNT to bring down the amount of data being requested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SELECT count(*) FROM ptfp1 WHERE ProposalNo = :input

Than check if the value you get is bigger than one. If it is, update it:

UPDATE ptfp1 set ... where ProposalNo = :input

else

INSERT INTO ptfp1(...) VALUES (...)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ProposalNo` has a unique index in the table, you can do it all in one query:

```
INSERT INTO ptfp1 (ProposalNo, colA, colB, colC, ...)
VALUES (:ProposalNo, :colA, :colB, :colC, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE colA = VALUES(colA), colB = VALUES(colB), colC = VALUES(colC), ...
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an answer. Just use the user's input (stored in a session variable) in my SELECT statement:

```
$pNoExists = $con->prepare("SELECT ProposalNo FROM ptfp1 WHERE ProposalNo =                                                                                                                             
'".$_SESSION['ProposalNo']."'"); 
$pNoExists->execute();
$row = $pNoExists->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And the button:

```
if($_POST['ButtonPush'] && !$row['ProposalNo']) {
  Write new record;
}
else {
  Update existing record;
}
```

Hiding in plain sight!